# Repairing geometry using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geometry

I have shapefile with few polygons. Some of them are self-intersecting. In ArcMap I can use "Repair geometry" tool, and it works well. But problem is, that for that task some users need to use open source or free tools.

I found tutorial on [link here](http://smsgis.co.za/using-qgis-fix-geometry-errors/) how to do that, but it is too hard to do it without explaining how it works.

Is there any other fast, one-click process for repairing geometry, like in ArcGIS software?

Comment: If QGIS will at least /draw/ the shapefile, you might try opening it in QGIS, then exporting it into a new shapefile. (Right-click the layer > Save as..) It's possible that in re-rendering the file, QGIS's internals will forcibly correct any basic problems with the geometries. I know [ogr2ogr has a reputation for doing this](http://www.spatiallyadjusted.com/ogr2ogr-every-shapefile/), so I'm speculating that QGIS may behave similarly.

Comment: Joseph - my question is about alternatives for very basic user, who don't need or want to know about GRASS :)

elrobis - I'll try to do that and update about my result.

Comment: elrobis - Only by saving ogr2ogr did not fix geometries, Qgis also.

Comment: @risk_ltu - I understand, I was confused for a while when I first used GRASS :). As an FYI, if you want to notify users then you should use the 'at' symbol **@** before their name. Otherwise they won't get a notification in their inbox :)

Comment: @Joseph - I made repairs with GRASS and it worked. Hope users will make it too :) Thanks!

Comment: @risk_ltu - Awesome, glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 plugins in QGIS 2.12 (current master) which will do most of the topo auto-correction:

- Geometry snapper
- Check Geometry

These should help.

Comment: I tested this tool but it look like it's still in beta stage so far. The (totally messy) dataset I tried to fix with this tools made qgis crash without any help context (tested on ubuntu & Win). Finally GRASS v.clean processing tool did the job for me.