# Automatically deleting lines within generated polygon using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon

How do I automatically delete lines within a generated polygon?

what I have: is a polygon with lines within. The lines I want to be deleted automatically -- like a auto clean up.

This is what I did:

1. opened a postcode shapefile from https://www.suche-postleitzahl.org
2. Selected features (Berlin postcodes)
3. Merged selected features
4. Struggling to find a way on how to clean up the polygon in the layer.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsAJp.jpg)

Comment: Those aren't lines, they're small polygon islands. This is because your source has small gaps. There are 3 posts that might help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167421/repairing-geometry-using-qgis and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112687/fixing-geometry-validity-errors-in-qgis but this one https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164296/how-to-fill-holes-in-polygons-automatically could be of most help.