# Tools for fixing geometry of shapefiles

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing

[image]does someone have experience in fixing geometry errors in QGIS 3.10 LTR? I'd like to fix geometries first and then use processing algorithm "Snap geometries to layer". So far, the algorithm doesn't work as there are still geometry errors. For fixing the geometry errors I used the processing algorithm "Fix geometries".

Comment: What kind of *geometry errors* are trying to fix? Can you provide some images?

Comment: Are you aware of these threads: [Repairing geometry using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167421/repairing-geometry-using-qgis), [Fixing geometry validity errors in QGIS 2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112687/fixing-geometry-validity-errors-in-qgis-2), [Handling Invalid Geometries (QGIS3)](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/handling_invalid_geometries.html) and [Geometry Checker Plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_geometry_checker.html?highlight=geometry%20checker%20plugin#geometry-checker-plugin)

Comment: Thanks, will hahve a look

Comment: Many times the errors are self intersections (check validity tool will tell you if they are) which usually wouldn't affect your use of other tools.  So in the Snap geometries tool you can change the invalid feature filtering to ignore invalid features.  You could configure Processing tools generally in the settings to not filter.